# Сравнить классы объектов, дочерних к общему классу

Tags: c#, классы, наследование

Есть класс А и его наследники: В, С.

Есть ссылка А1, которая указывает на объект класса В, и ссылка А2, которая указывает на объект класса С.

Предполагается что мы не знаем на объекты каких классов указывают ссылки A1 и A2.

Можно как то проверить что класс объекта по ссылке A1 не тот же класс, что класс объекта по ссылке А2 ?

Comment: Оператор [`instanceof`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0y7dd8cx%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) подходит?

Comment: @Arhad, не должен подходить.

Comment: `a1.GetType() == a2.GetType()`

Comment: @Igor, что ж все такие быстрые)))

Comment: @Qwertiy на английском StackOverflow у меня иногда возникает чувство, что там печатают ответы **раньше** вопросов

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```cs
if (!A1.GetType().Equals(A2.GetType())) {
    // Классы разные
} 
else {
    // Один и тот же класс
}
```

Comment: Зачем `Equals`, когда есть `==`? Это ж не джава.

Comment: Ты дал ответ первым, тебе и зачет) Но спасибо всем, вы очень быстрые))

Answer (score 2):

https://ideone.com/HH9UoV

```
using System;

public class Test
{
  class A {}
  class B : A {}
  class C : A {}

  public static void Main()
  {
    A a1b = new B(), a2c = new C(), a3b = new B();
    Console.WriteLine(a1b.GetType() == a2c.GetType());
    Console.WriteLine(a1b.GetType() == a3b.GetType());
  }
}
```